# Is there a way to load csv files saved in different folders with only a partial file name in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to load multiple csv files that are each saved in different folders within my working directory in R. However I only know part of each of the file name.

For example the file in "folder1" will be named "xxx_xxx_folder1.csv", and the file in "folder2" is "xxx_xxx_folder2.csv" *etc*. There is only one csv in each folder.

I was wondering is there a way to load files saved in different folders with only a partial file name?

The only way I have got it to partially work so far is to have all the files in one folder

Thanks and sorry if any of this is unclear!

Comment: Use `RStudio`. use the `import button` on its `environment tab, it will open a `dialog` form where you can navigate to any file you want on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you could use `list.files` with option `recursive=TRUE` to get a list of your csv files. You could then loop over the list to read your files:

```
fn <- list.files(PATH_TO_WORKING_DIRECTORY, "\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

lapply(fn, read.csv)
```